# How to merge 2 while loops in JAVA to avoid repitition

Tags: java, android

I want to merge multiple while loops without necessary repeting myself. I have an array of strings like so:

```
String[] myStrings = { "Home", "Two", "Three" };
```

My goal is to apply span effect when any of the array strings above are typed in editText. I could repeat the while loop and not use strings to begin with but for clean code, I want to put all strings in array and apply span effect to any of them if it’s typed in edit text. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String str="home";
            Spannable spannable =textA.getText();
            if(s.length() != 0) {
                textA.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
                ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan( Color.GREEN);
                String s1 = s.toString();
                int in=0; // start searching from 0 index

// keeps on searching unless there is no more function string found
                while ((in = s1.indexOf(str,in)) >= 0) {
                    spannable.setSpan(
                            fcs,
                            in,
                            in + str.length(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    // update the index for next search with length
                    in += str.length();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: The title of your question doesn't seem to match the actual question .... which one would you like an answer to?

Answer (score 3):

You may nest the actual loop that searches and decorates a specific `String` if it is encountered  by an outer loop that iterates on the set of `String`s to search and decorate.

```
for (String stringToSearch : myStrings){
   int in = 0; // start searching from 0 index for each new word to match
   while ((in = s1.indexOf(stringToSearch,in)) >= 0) {
    spannable.setSpan(
            fcs,
            in,
            in + stringToSearch.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    // update the index for next search with length
    in += stringToSearch.length();
  }
}
```

Comment: works but it is buggy. When you type the last element first before you type the first element, span doesn't apply

Comment: hi dave. Waiting for your reply please

Comment: Probably because you have to reinit `index` to `0` for each new `String` that you want to match for. I updated with the change. Give it a try.

Comment: hmm I already applied this trick david. Still doesn't solve this weird bug. as long as the last element is typed before the first element, the span is not applied to first element. I totally don't know why this bug exist

Comment: Well. Are you sure that you don't modify `s1` or that the problem is not in `spannable.setSpan()` ? You should probably run in debug mode with a breakpoint on this code to see how `in = s1.indexOf(stringToSearch,in))` is valued for the not added element.